# nodejs vuejs get post's comments (comments removed after add another comment)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, socket.io

``
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldYko.png

I want to get a comment once because came multiable times

```
getPosts(state) {
  let unique = [...new Set(state.posts)];

  for (let i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < unique[i].comments.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 1; k < unique[i].comments.length -1; k++) {
        if (unique[i].comments[j]._id == unique[i].comments[k]._id) {

          unique[i].comments.splice(k, 1)

        }
      }
    }
  }
  return unique;
},
```

---

server-side the code where the comment get

```
db.postSchema
              .findOne({ _id: comment.post })
              .populate("owner")
              .exec((err, users) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < array_of_connection.length; i++) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < users.owner.friends.length; j++) {
                    if (array_of_connection[i]._id == users.owner.friends[j]) {
                      array_of_connection[i].emit("new-comment", comment);
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
```

Comment: For future reference, never `splice` an array while looping it from left to right

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add a comment to the post , but a new comment is repeated more than one

Comment: So you want to remove duplicates?

Comment: exactly what i want

Comment: `unique.comments = Object.values(unique.comments.reduce((acc, comment) => (acc[comment._id] = comment, acc), {}));`, no `for` loops needed, full code: **https://jsfiddle.net/739tbf4h/**

Comment: ...this fixes the duplicates problem, but doesn't fix the real problem which is: why are you getting duplicates objects in the first place?

Comment: db.postSchema
              .findOne({ _id: comment.post })
              .populate("owner")
              .exec((err, users) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < array_of_connection.length; i++) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < users.owner.friends.length; j++) {
                    if (array_of_connection[i]._id == users.owner.friends[j]) {
                       array_of_connection[i].emit("new-comment", comment);
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
          });
         socket.emit("new-comment", comment);

Comment: unique.comments = Object.values(unique.comments.reduce((acc, comment) => (acc[comment._id] = comment, acc), {})), didn't solve the problem